# Some questions about the calendar bundle

Tags: calendar

1. I downloaded the [LaTeX Calendar Bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/calendar) and ran `latex allcal.ins` as recommended in the `README`. I haven't seen any effect (i.e., no `.sty` files have materialized). Is there a step I've missed?
2. I also saw in the documentation something that said, "the `.sty` file must be in the same directory as the `.tex` file for the calendar to compile correctly." That *looks* like it's saying that `calendar.sty` needs to be in with my documents, not in the TeX directory with rest of the TeX installation. Can that be?

Comment: You should try to install `calendar` with your package manager instead.  Which operating system are you using, and which distribution? (The latter is likely one of TeX Live, MacTeX, or MiKTeX.)

Comment: MacTeX (so, obviously, Mac OS). That bundle isn't listed in the repository, though.

Comment: You should download the entire [`calendar.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/calendar.zip), then run `latex allcall.ins` from the terminal and follow the on-screen instructions. This should install the package in the folder that you run it in.

Comment: Yeah, that was my fault... Accidentally installed to the wrong directory, which is why I saw no `.sty` files. Measure twice, cut once.